# Django Container Throwing Bad Request (400) on browser in aws eks

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, django-rest-framework, containers, amazon-eks

I have Containerized Django code, and it is successfully running on my local machine. But when I'm trying to deploy it on the AWS EKS Cluster, it throws a bad Request (400) on the browser.
Deploying it as deployment and service on it with loadbalncer
If I deploy another container of Django code in the same AWS EKS cluster, I'm able to access it from my browser, so I think there is some issue with the code only.
I also did '*' in ALLOWED HOST in settings.py in Django code.
Can anyone please help me with this?